# how to avoid memory error in generating and processing python permutations?

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7

I got a problem in calculating permutations. The program needs to generate
permutations(xrange(num), num)) and for each permutation I have to count the number of consecutive primes. i.e sum of every adjacent two digits in the number should be a prime.
max value 'num' would be 18

`primes = permutations(xrange(1,num+1), num)
for val in primes:
    for x in range(0,len(val-1)):
        if (prime(val[x] + val[x+1])):
             num_primes += 1`

if the 'num' range from 10 to 18, it is giving a response message of 
'killed' after a long waiting. please help me to solve this..

Comment: Given answer is obviously the problem. No point voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

There are 6402373705728000 permutations of 18 elements so it takes years to iterate over them. It should be better to think of an analytic solution for this problem.